# Does the MySQL database occupy storage space on web host server?

Tags: mysql, web, hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

When a web host offers storage space, say 5 GB,

1. do the MySQL database files occupy the 5 GB space?
2. where is the MySQL database stored?

Comment: Depends on the provider. Why don't you ask them?

Answer (score 0):

That depends if the server where your application is getting hosted happens to be the server where DB is also deployed. Means, the server they assign to you is the server where your application and DB both resides.